# ensure that all tmux session terminate when SSH session ends

Tags: ssh, tmux, ssh-tunneling

First off to anticipate confusion: this is indeed asking the opposite
of your run of the mill tmux question.

*How can one ensure that if the SSH tunnel dies, no tmux session
is leaked at all.* When running multiple shells over the same
SSH session, terminating the session and the tmux instance cleanly
in one terminal will still cause tmux instances in other terminals
to leak. This can cause all kinds of trouble if e. g. one forgot
to terminate a resource consuming process that was lingering hidden
in some backgrounded pane. Not cool.

I’m using tmux almost exclusively as a terminal emulator and have
little use if any for its “detach” feature. It’s not uncommon that
I have multiple tmux instances in terminals accessing the same
machine over a single SSH session. If I want to run a background
process, I ask the shell to `disown` it or run it in
systemd. Unfortunately, many systems I’m working with day to day
haven’t upgraded to systemd yet and are unlikely to do that in
the near future so `KillUserProcesses` is not an option.

Ideally I’d just invoke tmux with some command line switch that
prevents it from running in the background so I can alias that
to `tmux`.

> What SSH tunnels?

One OpenSSH connection serving multiple sessions.

> What tmux session?

Separate tmux instances, one per SSH session.

> What leaks?

Leaks of tmux instances. As in: SSH into a machine. Start another shell session
over the same connection. Start a tmux instance in each SSH session. You now
have two tmux instances. Stop tmux in one session (`<C-d>`); then stop the SSH
connection (again `<C-d>`): The other SSH session is closed but the tmux instance
running inside it is leaked with all it child processes.

> Please describe: (1) what setup you have now,

Stock OpenSSH, stock tmux, some shell. **Mostly reverse SSH connections**
that I cannot reestablish to at will, but that shouldn’t matter.

> and (2) what scenario you're trying to prevent.

Processes staying alive in the other tmux session.

Note that those are different boxes being SSH’d into, so the goal
is to prevent even a single tmux instance from remaining alive
after the connection dies. Also, since I use split panes and
backgrounded windows heavily, I really wish for all the child
processes to be collected.

Comment: _How can one ensure that if the SSH tunnel dies, no tmux session is leaked at all._ - What SSH tunnels?  What `tmux` session?  What leaks?  Please describe: (1) what setup you have now, and (2) what scenario you're trying to prevent.  Please skip rants about `systemd`, `disown`, and how you think they should work.  Just describe the problem.

Comment: Untested and incomplete: create a script that executes tmux and gets either its PID or session name (whichever is easier). Then `trap "kill $thepid" HUP` or `trap <however you delete a tmux session by name> HUP`

Answer (score 1):

When logging with new `ssh` session you can use something like `tmux attach -d || tmux new` to attach any existing `tmux` session or create a new session if no `tmux` sessions exist. While this won't prevent `tmux` session from running in background if you `ssh` connection drops, it will prevent these abandoned sessions from accumulating.

Comment: When the SSH connection fails this will leave all processes running inside that tmux session alive which is exactly the scenario I’m trying to avoid. Also I’m **not** attaching to the other session on purpose for multiple reasons.

Comment: As I understand it is Ok for you to run all these processes while you are connected but not Ok while you are not. Why? What is the difference?

Comment: *As I understand it is Ok for you to run all these processes while you are connected but not Ok while you are not.* -- Maintenance work on other people’s machines. If the connection goes down but a packet dump (real life example!) continues filling up disk space, you’re in trouble sooner than later.

Comment: I don't see a difference in this example. Packet dump will fill disk faster if you are still connected due to traffic generated by your connection.

Comment: *Packet dump will fill disk faster if you are still connected due to traffic generated by your connection.* Please read the question. The point is for tcpdump to terminate if the SSH connection fails. Besides, in the example scenario the SSH connection wasn’t even captured.

Comment: Your problem isn't that processes are still running if the connection drops but that you are losing track of your processes. If you leave such process like a tcpdump without attention but still connected it will fill your disk the same way as disconnected. To reduce chances of losing attention to such process, keep only single ssh session with single tmux instance and just open additional tmux windows. You can always see your open tmux windows in its status bar. If you lose your single ssh connection you'll notice it immediately and can bring your tmux back with command I gave in answer.

Answer (score 1):

I believe your problem can be avoided entirely by using [Mosh](https://mosh.org/).

Mosh supports intermittent connectivity, and only leaks `mosh-server` instances if you don't disconnect properly (such as forcefully closing the client while disconnected from the server).